# How to get the braces in the multirow spanning all three rows?

Tags: multirow, brackets

In the following table I would like to have the braces in both multirows span the three rows that the multirow is covering. I tried using `\left.\right\}` and editing the vertical space, but nothing has worked so far.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|l|c|r|r|}
\hline
Area        & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Residents}   & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Number of Calls}     & Percentage Moving Calls \\
\hline
Zuidhorn    & 6,878             & 38.3          & (6.128)   & 6     & \multirow{3}{*}{\}16} & 0\%   \\
Aduard      & 2,253             & 12.6          & (2.016)   & 3     &                       & 0\%   \\
Lewenborg   & 8,800             & 49.1          & (7.856)   & 8     &                       & 0\%   \\
\cline{2-6}
Groningen   & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{171,201}     & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{300}                 & 40\%  \\ 
\cline{2-6}
Hoogkerk    & 14,640            & 42.8\%        & (12.84)   & 13    & \multirow{3}{*}{\}30} & 70\%  \\
Haren       & 18,656            & 54.6\%        & (16.38)   & 16    &                       & 70\%  \\
Engelbert   & 870               & 2.6 \%        & (0.78)    & 1     &                       & 70\%  \\
\hline \hline
Total       & 223,298           &               &           &       &                       &       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: have you tried `{\Bigg{\}}16}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like `\multirow{3}{*}{$\left. \vphantom{\begin{tabular}{c}3\\3\\3\end{tabular}}\right\}$16}`?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! it is indeed a solution to the problem, {\Bigg{\}}16} is a better (shorter) solution probably

Answer (score 7):

A simpler method is to use `\bigdelim`,

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Number of Calls} \\
            \hline
            (6.128) & 6 & \rdelim\}{3}{20pt}[16]  \\                
            (2.016) & 3 &                         \\                
            (7.856) & 8 &                         \\                
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: Table using bigdelim]

Answer (score 2):

The `scalerel` package is also an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|l|c|r|r|}
\hline
Area & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Residents} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Number of
Calls}     & Percentage Moving Calls \\
\hline
Zuidhorn & 6,878 & 38.3 & (6.128) & 6 &
\multirow{3}{*}{\scalerel*[1ex]{\}}{\rule[-2.8ex]{1ex}{7.2ex}}17} & 0\% \\
Aduard & 2,253 & 12.6 & (2.016) & 3 & & 0\%   \\
Lewenborg & 8,800 & 49.1 & (7.856) & 8 & & 0\%   \\
\cline{2-6}
Groningen & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{171,201} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{300} &
40\%  \\ 
\cline{2-6}
Hoogkerk & 14,640 & 42.8\% & (12.84) & 13 &
\multirow{3}{*}{\scalerel*[1ex]{\}}{\rule[-2.8ex]{1ex}{7.2ex}}30} & 70\%
\\
Haren & 18,656 & 54.6\% & (16.38) & 16 & & 70\%  \\
Engelbert & 870 & 2.6 \% & (0.78) & 1 & & 70\%  \\
\hline \hline
Total & 223,298 & & & & &       \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]