# How to create braces which span multi-lines in a table?

Tags: tables, math-mode, multirow

This is my template code for the table I'd like to create:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{cllll}
\multirow{3}{*}{multirow} &  &  &  &  \\
                          &  &  &  &  \\
                          &  &  &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How can I insert a right brace which should be placed between the first and second column and span the first three lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108991/how-to-get-the-braces-in-the-multirow-spanning-all-three-rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like one of these, with package `bigdelim`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}    
\begin{tabular}{c@{\,}c@{\,}llll}
\multirow{3}{*}{multirow} & \ldelim\{{3}{*} & aaa& bb & cde & fg\\
                              & &tt & xxx & y& zz\\
                              & & mn & op & & rss\\[1ex]
    A & & B & C & D & E

\end{tabular}
\vskip 4ex
\begin{tabular}{c@{\,}llll}
 \ldelim\{{3}{*}[multirow] & aaa& bb & cde & fg\\
                               &tt & xxx & y& zz\\
                              & mn & op & & rss\\[1ex]
    A & B & C & D & E

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]