# How to typeset a complicated align environment with lots of braces spanning several lines

Tags: tables, align, multirow, arrays, braces

I would like to typeset the plan of a complicated proof - something like an align environment, but with lots of braces spanning multiple lines on both sides. Here is a rough picture of what I want:

```
                                       / Property 6
                / Property 2      <=> <            
                |                      \ Prooooperty 7  \
                |                                        |
                |                      / Property 8      |
                | Proooperty 3 \       |                 |       / Property 11
Property 1 <=> <                > <=> <  Property 9       > <=> <
                | Property 4   /       |                 |       \ Property 12
                |                      \ Property 10     |
                |                                        |
                \ Property 5             Property 5      /
```

How do I typeset this?

Of course, all of these "properties" have various widths (I tried to simulate this with varying numbers of "o"'s) and various heights.

I found a possible lead here: [How to create braces which span multi-lines in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474852/how-to-create-braces-which-span-multi-lines-in-a-table) . However this leads to too much spacing around each, and the result would not fit into the available textwidth.

Comment: My positive vote for the picture :-)

Comment: I would do that with an `array` environment, using the `bigdelim`  package (which come with `multirow`) for the braces. Other possibility: nested `cases` and `rcases`(defined by `mathtools`) environments.

Comment: `bigdelim` is indeed how it is done in the linked question, but it leads to too much horizontal spacing. I would like to model the look of `cases` and `rcases`; unfortunately the issue is precisely that the braces are not nested. Also, ensuring proper vertical alignment would be a pain - it would be really nice to have the power of `multirow` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a lot of fiddling, but with `multirow` and `bigdelim` it is possible. To eliminate the whitespace in the columns reserved for the braces I use `@{}` and then to adjust the spacing use some `\hspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\newcommand\RD[1]{\rdelim\}{#1}{8mm}[$<=>$]}
\newcommand\LD[1]{\ldelim\{{#1}{8mm}[$<=>$]}
\newcommand\LLD[1]{\ldelim\{{#1}{0.3mm}[\hspace*{2mm}]}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r @{}r l @{\extracolsep{3mm}}r l @{}r @{}c l l}
%
%      1      {          3             }    {     6          }      {       9
%    
            &       &              & \LD3 & Property 6    &  &                     &             \\
            &\LD{10}& Property 2   &      &               &  &                     &             \\
            &       &              &      & Prooooperty 7 &\RD9 &                  &             \\
            &       &              &      &               &  &                     &             \\     
            &       &              &\LLD5 & Property 8    &  &                     &             \\
 \multirow{2}*{Property 1}
            &       & Proooperty 3 & \RD3 &               &  & \hspace{-2mm}\LLD3 & Property 11  \\
            &       &              &      & Property 9    &  &                     &             \\
            &       & Property 4   &      &               &  &                     & Property 12 \\
            &       &              &      & Property 10   &  &                     &             \\
            &       &              &      &               &  &                     &             \\
            &       & Property 5   &      & Property 5    &  &                     &             \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice try; indeed, this gives a decent approximation of what I am looking for. However, no matter how I tweak this, there is no way I can make it look really clean - i.e. make the $\iff$ signs vertically aligned, get consistent spacing between the $\iff$ signs and the braces, and get consistent spacing between the braces and the text. This last point is more than a purely cosmetic issue, as extra horizontal space prevents this diagram from fitting into the text width...

Comment: OK, I managed to make this work. In fact, I simply put the $\iff$'s on their own columns, set all the width arguments to `*`, removed all the (positive or negative) `\hspace`s, and put `@{}` everywhere, between all columns.

Comment: "put `@{}` everywhere".
In that case it is easier to use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` (or `arraycolsep` if you use an `array` environment.